# How can I darken the background behind a div popup?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-events, dom-manipulation

Like I've written in the title, I created a div popup that shows up when you press the 'change my grid' button but I'd like to darken the background when it appears but also make the background unclickable (I wouldn't like the background to be completely dark though. I'd like the stuff in the background to be still visible a little bit).

How can I do? My idea was to set a div that should apper with the event listener that gets run when you click on the change grid button but it doesn't work; better to say that the new div appears (I checked with `console.log()`) but it doesn't have the effect that I was hoping for. Would you procede with my idea or you would propose another one?

I leave you the code with some comments to identify the new background div!

Thank you!

```js
//FUNCTION TO MAKE THE GRID

function makeGrid(a, b) {
    const container = document.querySelector('#screen');
    let divRow = undefined;

    for (i = 0; a > i; i++) {
        divRow = document.createElement('div')
        container.appendChild(divRow);
    }

    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div');
    let divColumn = undefined;

    containers.forEach(function (div) {
        for (i = 0; b > i; i++) {
            divColumn = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(divColumn)
        }
    })
}
makeGrid(30, 50);



// TO MAKE THE RANDOM COLORS

  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div div');

function randomValue() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function randomColor() {
    return `rgb(${randomValue()}, ${randomValue()}, ${randomValue()})`;
}

function changeBackground() {
    let opacity = 0;
this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
console.log(randomColor());
}

squares.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', changeBackground, {once: true});
});





// Start from here!!!

// EVENTS: HOVERING AND CLICKING THE BUTTONS


const container = document.getElementById('container') 
const backgroundDiv = document.createElement('div');
backgroundDiv.setAttribute('id', 'background')
/*Up here it's how I tryed to set a div for a new background
that should appear when you press the change grid button in order to 
darken everything but the popup*/

const btnChangeGrid = document.getElementById('change-grid');
const btnRefresh = document.getElementById('refresh');
const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');
btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {this.classList.add('hover-style')});
btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {this.classList.remove('hover-style')});
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {this.classList.add('hover-style')});
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {this.classList.remove('hover-style')});

btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mousedown', openPopUp);
btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {this.classList.remove('click-style')});
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mousedown', resetBackground);
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {this.classList.remove('click-style')});

function openPopUp() {
    this.classList.add('click-style');
    popup.classList.add('opened-popup');
    container.appendChild(backgroundDiv); // <--- The new div background 
}

function resetBackground() {
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div div');
    squares.forEach(element => element.style.setProperty('background-color', null));
    this.classList.add('click-style');
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /*border: solid 2px;*/
    box-shadow: inset 0px -20px 20px  1px #1d321d;

    background: linear-gradient(380deg, black, 5%, #72c077);
}

#box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 542px;
    width: 680px;
    border: solid 1px 0px 1px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 20px 10px #e20000,
                inset 0px -8px 10px #340000,
                0px 10.5px 15px 5px #200000;


    background-color: #8a0000;

}

#shell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 400px;
    width: 670px;
    border-radius: 26px 26px 0px 0px;

    background-color: #dc0000;
}

#screen-border {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 320px;
    width: 520px;
    border-top: solid 5px #bd0202;
    border-right: solid 2px white;
    border-left: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0px white,
                inset 0px -8px 10px #dc0000,
                inset -1.5px 0px white;

    background-color: #9a0000;
}

#screen {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border-top: solid 0.1px #292828;
    border-right: solid 0.1px rgba(41, 40, 40, 0.75);
    border-left: solid 0.1px rgba(41, 40, 40, 0.75);

    background-color: #cdcdcd
}

#inner-screen {
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px #b30202,
    inset 0px 10px 10px -8px #121212,
    inset -8px 0px 10px -4px #343434,
    inset 8px 0px 10px -4px #343434;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#screen div {                /*THESE ARE THE ROWS...*/
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#screen div div {             /*...AND THESE ARE THE LITTLE SQUARES INSIDE THE ROWS!!*/
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
}


#knobs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 130px;
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 18px 18px;

    background-color: #dc0000;
}


#central-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    /*border: solid 1px white;*/
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #fff0f0;
    
}
#central-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #fff0f0;
}


#outer-left, #outer-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 102px;
    width: 102px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #382929;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #bebebe;
}
#outer-left {
    margin-left: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                8px -1px 20px #382929;
}
#outer-right {
    margin-right: 20px; 
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                -8px -1px 20px #382929;

}


#inner-left, #inner-right {
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
#inner-left {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0px #cecece;
                /*5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac,;*/
                

}
#inner-right {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 10px #cecece;
                /*-5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac;*/
                 

}

button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 215px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
   padding: 30px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', 'Comic Sans', cursive;

   box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #263c26;

   transition: all 0.1s;
}

.hover-style {
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 25px -5px #263c26;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.click-style {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #263c26;
    transform: scale(.98);
}

#popup {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    transform: scale(0.01);
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    width: 840px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #263c26;

    background-color: #72c077;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup.opened-popup {
    top: initial;
    transform: scale(1);
    visibility: visible;
}

#background {                         /* <--- The style of the new div */
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, blue, 1);
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="container">

        <button id="change-grid">Change my grid!</button>

        <div id="box">

            <div id="shell">

                <div id="screen-border">
                    <div id="screen">
                        <span id="inner-screen"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="knobs">

                <div id="outer-left">
                    <div id="central-left">
                        <div id="inner-left"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="outer-right">
                    <div id="central-right">
                        <div id="inner-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
       
            <button id="refresh">Refresh me!</button>
        
        <div id="popup">
            <button id="small">Small</button>
            <button id="medium">Medium</button>
            <button id="large">large</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add an onclick listener to the button and create a pseudo element when you click on it.

```js
//FUNCTION TO MAKE THE GRID

function makeGrid(a, b) {
    const container = document.querySelector('#screen');
    let divRow = undefined;

    for (i = 0; a > i; i++) {
        divRow = document.createElement('div')
        container.appendChild(divRow);
    }

    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div');
    let divColumn = undefined;

    containers.forEach(function (div) {
        for (i = 0; b > i; i++) {
            divColumn = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(divColumn)
        }
    })
}
makeGrid(30, 50);



// TO MAKE THE RANDOM COLORS

  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div div');

function randomValue() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function randomColor() {
    return `rgb(${randomValue()}, ${randomValue()}, ${randomValue()})`;
}

function changeBackground() {
    let opacity = 0;
this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
//console.log(randomColor());
}

squares.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', changeBackground, {once: true});
});





// Start from here!!!

// EVENTS: HOVERING AND CLICKING THE BUTTONS


const container = document.getElementById('container') 
const backgroundDiv = document.createElement('div');
backgroundDiv.setAttribute('id', 'background')
/*Up here it's how I tryed to set a div for a new background
that should appear when you press the change grid button in order to 
darken everything but the popup*/

const btnChangeGrid = document.getElementById('change-grid');
const btnRefresh = document.getElementById('refresh');
const popup = document.querySelector('#popup');
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {this.classList.add('hover-style')});
btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {this.classList.remove('hover-style')});
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {this.classList.add('hover-style')});
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {this.classList.remove('hover-style')});

btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mousedown', openPopUp);
btnChangeGrid.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  this.classList.remove('click-style');
});
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mousedown', resetBackground);
btnRefresh.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {this.classList.remove('click-style')});

function openPopUp() {
    this.classList.add('click-style');
    popup.classList.add('opened-popup');
    container.appendChild(backgroundDiv); // <--- The new div background 
}

function resetBackground() {
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll('#screen div div');
    squares.forEach(element => element.style.setProperty('background-color', null));
    this.classList.add('click-style');
}

function addBackdrop() {
  document.getElementById('body').classList.add('backdrop');
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    /*border: solid 2px;*/
    box-shadow: inset 0px -20px 20px  1px #1d321d;

    background: linear-gradient(380deg, black, 5%, #72c077);
}

#box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 542px;
    width: 680px;
    border: solid 1px 0px 1px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 20px 10px #e20000,
                inset 0px -8px 10px #340000,
                0px 10.5px 15px 5px #200000;


    background-color: #8a0000;

}

#shell {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 400px;
    width: 670px;
    border-radius: 26px 26px 0px 0px;

    background-color: #dc0000;
}

#screen-border {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 320px;
    width: 520px;
    border-top: solid 5px #bd0202;
    border-right: solid 2px white;
    border-left: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: inset 1.5px 0px white,
                inset 0px -8px 10px #dc0000,
                inset -1.5px 0px white;

    background-color: #9a0000;
}

#screen {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    border-top: solid 0.1px #292828;
    border-right: solid 0.1px rgba(41, 40, 40, 0.75);
    border-left: solid 0.1px rgba(41, 40, 40, 0.75);

    background-color: #cdcdcd
}

#inner-screen {
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px #b30202,
    inset 0px 10px 10px -8px #121212,
    inset -8px 0px 10px -4px #343434,
    inset 8px 0px 10px -4px #343434;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#screen div {                /*THESE ARE THE ROWS...*/
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#screen div div {             /*...AND THESE ARE THE LITTLE SQUARES INSIDE THE ROWS!!*/
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
}


#knobs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 130px;
    width: 670px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 18px 18px;

    background-color: #dc0000;
}


#central-left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    /*border: solid 1px white;*/
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #fff0f0;
    
}
#central-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
    margin-right: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #fff0f0;
}


#outer-left, #outer-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 102px;
    width: 102px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #382929;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #bebebe;
}
#outer-left {
    margin-left: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset -2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                8px -1px 20px #382929;
}
#outer-right {
    margin-right: 20px; 
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px #a2a2a2, 
                -8px -1px 20px #382929;

}


#inner-left, #inner-right {
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
#inner-left {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-left: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0px #cecece;
                /*5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac,;*/
                

}
#inner-right {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    box-shadow: inset -3px 3px 10px #cecece;
                /*-5px 4px 10px 2px #acacac;*/
                 

}

button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 215px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-bottom: 4px solid;
   padding: 30px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', 'Comic Sans', cursive;

   box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #263c26;

   transition: all 0.1s;
}

.hover-style {
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 25px -5px #263c26;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
.click-style {
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #263c26;
    transform: scale(.98);
}

#popup {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    transform: scale(0.01);
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    width: 840px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #263c26;

    background-color: #72c077;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#popup.opened-popup {
    top: initial;
    transform: scale(1);
    visibility: visible;
}

#background {                         /* <--- The style of the new div */
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, blue, 1);
}

body.backdrop::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
<div id="container">

        <button id="change-grid" onclick="addBackdrop()">Change my grid!</button>

        <div id="box">

            <div id="shell">

                <div id="screen-border">
                    <div id="screen">
                        <span id="inner-screen"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="knobs">

                <div id="outer-left">
                    <div id="central-left">
                        <div id="inner-left"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="outer-right">
                    <div id="central-right">
                        <div id="inner-right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
       
            <button id="refresh">Refresh me!</button>
        
        <div id="popup">
            <button id="small">Small</button>
            <button id="medium">Medium</button>
            <button id="large">large</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  <body>
```

PS: open in full window while running the snippet.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yeah, this the solution that I'd like to achive but I still can draw the color behind the popup. Also, when I click the button, and I don't move the pointer away, it doesn't get affected by the effect. It stays normal and just when you remove the pointer it goes in the background. Any idea for these two problems? I keep searching meanwhile!